# Consumir API con JavaScript y retornar datos en variable

Tags: javascript, api

tengo el siguiente código JS lo que hace es consumir una API con fetch que devuelve un precio de una criptomoneda y luego lo muestro en un elemento html. Ahora bien lo que quiero es obtener el resultado de la consulta asignado a una variable para luego poder hacer operaciones aritméticas con esa variable.

```js
function api(){
    fetch('https://petroapp-price.petro.gob.ve/price/', {
      method: 'POST', 
      body: JSON.stringify({"coins": ["PTR"],"fiats" : ["BS"]}), 
      headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
    .then(function(response){return response.json();})
    .then(response => {
      document.getElementById('precio').innerHTML = parseFloat(response.data.PTR.BS).toFixed(2);
    });
  }

  api();
```

```html
<span id="precio"></span>
```

Quiero asignar el valor que devuelve el reponse a una variable. Ya había probado asignando directamente el resultado a una variable pero resulta que la respuesta a la consulta de la api tarda, entonces la variable queda con un valor de `undefined` y quiero poder realizar operaciones matemáticas.
Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Tu duda es como asignar el valor que te regresa el `response` entonces en una variable para operarlo matemáticamente en tu HTML?

Comment: Algo como: `.then(response => { let precio = parseFloat(response.data.PTR.BS).toFixed(2); ... }`? La verdad no entiendo bien si esta es tu duda. Asignar el valor de `response` a una variable como muestro aquí, para luego ir operando con la misma. Saludos

Comment: Si, quiero asignar el valor que devuelve el reponse a una variable. Ya había probado con tu solución pero resulta que la respuesta a la consulta de la api tarda, entonces la variable queda con un valor de `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Prueba del siguiente modo:

- Con una estructura condicional simple: **`if/else`** verificas si el valor que tiene `response` es igual a **`undefined`**, en caso afirmativo mandas a la vista un mensaje al respecto
- En el bloque de **`else`** asignas el valor que se obtuvo de `response` a una variable que previamente ya fue declarada
- Aparte pudieras agregar en tu encadenamiento el uso de **`catch`** para manejar un eventual error que se pudiera llegar a presentar al momento de la petición, es decir si dicha petición presenta un fallo y la promesa devuelve `rejected`

**Código**

```
<span id="precio"></span>
<script>
function api(){
    fetch('url/de/la/peticion/con/fetch', {
      method: 'POST', 
      body: JSON.stringify({"coins": ["PTR"],"fiats" : ["BS"]}), 
      headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
    .then(function(response){return response.json();})
    .then(response => {
      let valor = 0
      if(response === undefined) {
        document.getElementById('precio').innerHTML = "Pendiente obtener valor"
      } else {
        valor = parseFloat(response.data.PTR.BS).toFixed(2)
        document.getElementById('precio').innerHTML = valor;
        console.log(valor)
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      document.getElementById('precio').innerHTML = error.message
    });
  }

  api();
</script>
```